# SDL2: smooth movement on 16 x 16 grid

Tags: c++, sdl, game-development

I want a dot to move on a grid from tile to tile. Tiles are 16x16.

This is my game loop:

```
int nextMoveTime = 0;
while (!quit) //gameloop
{
    //Handle events on queue
    while (SDL_PollEvent(&e) != 0)
    {
        //User requests quit
        if (e.type == SDL_QUIT)
        {
            quit = true;
        }

        //Handle input for the dot
        dot.handleEvent(e);//adjusts velocity in increments of 16
    }
    if (nextMoveTime <= SDL_GetTicks())
    {
        dot.move(tileSet);//applies velocity
        nextMoveTime = SDL_GetTicks() + 100;
    }

     //and some render stuff:
     dot.setCamera(camera);

    //Clear screen
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(gRenderer, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF);
    SDL_RenderClear(gRenderer);

    //Render level
    for (int i = 0; i < TOTAL_TILES; ++i)
    {
        tileSet[i]->render(camera);
    }

    //Render dot
    dot.render(camera,frame);
    //Update screen
    SDL_RenderPresent(gRenderer);
}
```

I feel like this is a bad approach since the velocity increments by 16 so the movement on a 16x16 grid does not look smooth, i would like to render the dot once in between tiles.

Comment: Are you rendering directly to the screen or to a buffer then from the buffer to the screen?

Comment: I use something like texture.render();

Comment: Ok. And what is your question ? I think you should read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Comment: My dot's movement looks choppy and not smooth. How can i make it  smoother?

Comment: That should be in the question, not as a comment! Click on "edit".